Soft Close option for surface/face hinge?
Does a soft-close option exist for face/face hinges like this?
Hinge

Yes, that option does exist.

Yes, BLUM makes a soft-closer fitting that costs under $5 USD.   They screw to the cabinet frame and have a damped plunger which provides the soft-close action you're looking for.  I used these on my cabinets and they worked great.
BLUM part #971A0700
They also have a variation (part #971A9700.22) to consider.
I'd recommend ordering one to ensure they'll work in your exact application.

Thanks for the response. These two models though look like the type I've seen already that SEEM to be designed for hidden/European style hinges. The issue seems to be that the European style hinges have enough 'pull back' force to properly close when the dampers are installed - whereas the face frame style hinge (with no sort of spring in them) won't close properly with these style dampers.
So...been trying to find a damper that is specifically designed for a face frame hinge.
